# Prism: Exception handling?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm getting an odd result in a Composite Event handler in a Prism app I am writing. I created the event handler and put in an exception statement to verify that the handler is being called:

```
public void OnDateSelected(DateTime selectedDate)
{
    // Temporary code
    throw new ApplicationException("Not implemented yet.");
}
```

I run the app and raise the event. The event handler is called, but the exception does not stop execution. It is written to the output window, and the app exits the handler, but execution continues. There isn't a try-catch block anywhere in sight, so why isn't the exception interrupting execution? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

We figured out the problem here. We are using v2.2 of the prism libraries. In the BackgroundEventSubscription class, when the event is being published, a background worker is created and invoked. The RunWorkerCompleted delegate is never handled so the exceptions are never picked up anywhere. The prism library also does not give the end user a simple way to apply their own delegate in this version. The solution is to either compile your own set of libraries and use the threadpool (this is what we did) or override Subscribe of your own CompositePresentationEvent class and use your own event subscription class that does what you need.

The prism v4 libraries have addressed this issue as it is using the thread pool so any unhandled exceptions will bubble up to the domain unhandled exception handler (if you specified one).

Thanks.